# messageReactionAdd firing more than once

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

It seems that the block of code runs more than 1 after 1 try,  even though I only called it once

The code's function is to wait for a reaction and then wait for a message and save that message in a .json file

**main.js**

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);

    const command = args.shift().toLocaleLowerCase();

   
    if (command == story) {
        client.commands.get('story').execute(message, args, Discord, client, fs);
    }



});
```

**command story.js**

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
                if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
                if (reaction.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
                if (user.bot) return;
                if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

                if (reaction.message.channel.id = channel) {

                    if (reaction.emoji.name === emoj) {
                        const filter = m => {
                            return m.author.id === message.author.id;
                        }

                        message.channel.send('Input Story').then(msg => {
                           
                            msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                                max: 1,
                                time: 30000
                            })
                                .then(swag => {
                                    swag = swag.first()
                                    client.msgs[swag.author.username] = {
                                        message: swag.content
                                    }
                                    fs.writeFile("./Database/msgs.json", JSON.stringify(client.msgs, null, 4), err => {
                                        if (err) throw err;
                                        message.channel.send("logged");
                                       
                                    });

                                })
                        })
                    }


                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you include the upper scope (or even the whole code) ? Maybe you are creating the listener twice ?

Comment: I edited the problem and included the main file that called the block file. Does the double client.on mean i have been listening twice?

Comment: You did not include the upper scope of the listener declaration. Each `client.on(...)` registers a listener. If it ruens twice, you will have 2 identical listeners (though not the same function reference)

Comment: Can I ask for advice?
I already tried awaitReactions and awaitMessages to log the message sent after the user reacts the emoji and it seems that there is an error

Comment: Again, please add the upper scope of the listener declaration in your code block, and if possible, the entire file.

Comment: Can I ask how to do that?

Comment: Simply copy and paste your code.